# Sort map (deck.gl Scatterplot) legend in Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset, deck.gl

is there a way to sort legend alphabetically or even better with a custom given order in Apache Superset? e.g. in example image below, I want the order A, B, C, D for the legend.

(I have the same question on numerical legend as well)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible right now. Can you open a Github ticket? There is a lot of work in the visualization and with a ticket can be prioritized.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eugenia. I opened a ticket here: https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/13316